# Why npm commands are not running in my pc? All commands were running smoothly till last night, i have not change any settings also

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm

PS D:\My Web Development\express learning> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\My Web Development\express learning/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\My Web Development\express learning\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs
npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eZ2m.png)

Comment: You should be in the same directory as your `package.json` is when you are running `npm` commands. Please check if you are the right folder. From your screenshot it seems like you deleted the package.json. Recover the file or recreate a package.json